# Query string paginação com codeigniter

Tags: string, codeigniter, query, paginação

Como posso fazer busca com paginação usando query string no CodeIgniter? Estou tentando procurar na documentação mas não encontrei! Tenho seguinte cenário:

```
http://localhost/meusite/procurar/s?search_state=RJ&search_city=Rio+de+Janeiro
```

Se fosse em uma pagina sem busca ficaria fácil, bastaria indicar a página principal que será exibida a listagem, mas como um sistema de busca como faço para quando clicar na próxima página manter o critério da busca no get?

Comment: Apesar de estar em inglês, é um exemplo interessante que pode te ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542031/how-to-make-pagination-query-string-in-codeigniter

Comment: @RicardoPontual não tem problema estar em outro idioma, mas ali é com apenas uma query string, no meu caso são duas, sem contar que depois virá a da paginação! O problema maior está que o uri->segment so identifica o até o 'S' e ignora totalmente o resto, sendo assim eu não consigo passar todo o link para o array $config['base_url']

Comment: Obrigado @RicardoPontual pela disposição em ajudar, editei o post da maneira que consegui resolver, não sei se foi a melhor maneira, mas resolveu pra mim, obrigado novamente!

Comment: @ThiMoreira, você pode responder sua própria pergunta :). Coloque a solução como resposta e aprove ela. Depois pode remover o "RESPONDIDO" do título da sua pergunta e, de preferência, remover a solução da sua pergunta. Assim fica mais organizado. Entendeu? E seja bem-vindo ao SOpt!

Comment: Desculpa @Dherik por ter feito a edição de forma errada, sou novo aqui e ainda não adaptei! Obrigado pelo conselho!

Comment: @ThiMoreira, que isto, acabou de chegar, normal cometer alguns erros :). O SOpt agradece a edição! rs. Aliás, você pode aceitar sua resposta clicando no botão de checkmark

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVIDO DA SEGUINTE FORMA:

Como o problema era identificar qual seria o número da paginação, então fiz dessa forma, não sei se é a melhor, mas funcionou pra mim:

```
     $state   = $this->input->get('search_state');
     $city    = $this->input->get('search_city');

     $urlExp  =  explode("=", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] );

     $maximum                   = 1;
     $start                     = isset( $urlExp[3] ) ? $urlExp[3] : 0;

     $config['base_url']        = base_url( 'procurar/result?search_state=' .$state. '&search_city=' .$city. '' );
```